# AWS : cannot execute binary file

Tags: c++, linux, amazon-web-services

My server is a **Amazon Linux AMI 64bits** ([2014.09-release-notes](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2014.09-release-notes/))

I compiled a program coded in C++ (*gcc48-c++.x86_64* is installed) :

```
[root@ip-***-**-**-*** waveform_generator]# make
Compiled    [src/main.cpp] >> [src/main.o]
Compiled    [src/File.cpp] >> [src/File.o]
Compiled    [src/AGenerator.cpp] >> [src/AGenerator.o]
Compiled    [src/GeneratorSVG.cpp] >> [src/GeneratorSVG.o]
Compiled    [src/GeneratorCanvas.cpp] >> [src/GeneratorCanvas.o]
Compiled    [src/GeneratorPNG.cpp] >> [src/GeneratorPNG.o]
Compiled    [src/Header.cpp] >> [src/Header.o]
Compiled    [src/pngwriter.cpp] >> [src/pngwriter.o]
Built       [wfgen]
```

Now when I execute the compiled file "wfgen" the console return this message :

```
[root@ip-***-**-**-*** waveform_generator]# bash wfgen
wfgen: wfgen: cannot execute binary file
```

Environment :

```
[root@ip-***-**-**-*** waveform_generator]# uname -i
x86_64
[root@ip-***-**-**-*** waveform_generator]# file wfgen
wfgen: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=2e7c881c6fc10f12cdf49402edae1cc36b8d77a0, not stripped
```

Do you have a solution to my problem?

Thank you a lot :)

Max.

Comment: Could you please deactivate colored output and re-run the `make`? It's really hard to read what's happening there.

Comment: Ok, it's Ok :) I delete colors codes

Comment: Much better. :) I've taken the liberty to remove the tabs, too.

Answer (score 2):

When you type

```
[root@ip-***-**-**-*** waveform_generator]# bash wfgen
```

I think bash expects wfgen to be a shell script. Instead you could directly type the program name at th e prompt

```
[root@ip-***-**-**-*** waveform_generator]#./wfgen
```

Comment: Yeah, you're maybe right for shell script interpretation...

But I try directly `./wfgen` or `wfgen` and I have absolutely no return!

Comment: @maxsennin Sorry I did not get you. Does it print anything on the terminal?

Comment: @maxsennin: If you don't get output, what do you get when executing `./wfgen ; echo $?`?

Comment: Also, what does `./wfgen --help` give you?

Comment: I have anything with `./wfgen`
And `./wfgen ; echo $?`return just `1`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the compiling went fine, the output of the `file` command looks good. I don't know what's in the Makefile, but guess it'll be fine, too.

I don't really know your environment, so I'm taking a bit of a guess here: If everything else went fine, and you still get the `cannot execute binary file` error, then it can be because your filesystem is mounted with the `noexec` option.

To check if that's the case, run `mount`, then determine under which mount point the current directory is, and check if the `noexec` mount option is set for this mount point.

If it's indeed the `noexec` problem, you have two options:

1. Remount the filesystem without the `noexec` option. If you want this to be permanent, don't forget to edit `/etc/fstab`. (Note however that `noexec` might be there for a reason. Make sure it's ok to remove it.)
2. If it's only one binary, move it to a filesystem that doesn't have the `noexec` restriction and try from there. A good place would be the `/usr/local/bin` directory (or `/usr/local/sbin`, if it's an administrative tool.)

Comment: When I run `mount` there is no sign of "noexec".
I try to move the file "wfgen" in /usr/local/bin and same result... :/

Comment: Argh, I now see that you're trying to execute the file with bash. This can't work of course, as it's a binary. You need to `chmod +x` the binary then call it with `./wfgen` (as Sayu proposed). That should be it.

Comment: You mean like `chmod 0777 /` ?

Comment: **NOOOO**, not `0777`, and especially not `/`. (Good thing it wouldn't work without the `-R` flag, otherwise you would make your *entire* system readable/writable/executable for *anyone*.) A simple `chmod 755 filename` should do. To learn more about file permissions, read http://catcode.com/teachmod/

Comment: Woups ^^ Okey... I try and same result, I have nothing :/